# Create a panda's dataframe from Selenium results

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

m.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://tradingview.com/screener/')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 35)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-set='income_statement']"))).click()
    
    # Scroll down 100 times
i  = 1
while i < 75:
        print(i)
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        i += 1
        sleep(1)


delay = 5 #seconds
  
  # table updated, get the data
for row in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".tv-data-table__tbody tr"):

       print(row.text)
```

**Example of Results**

```
AAPLD
APPLE INC
5.67USD 5.66USD 5.61USD 121.463BUSD 35.174BUSD 152.836BUSD 365.817BUSD 5.61USD 365.817BUSD 94.68BUSD
MSFTD
MICROSOFT CORP.
8.12USD 9.01USD 8.95USD 86.531BUSD 31.671BUSD 115.856BUSD 168.088BUSD 8.05USD 168.088BUSD 61.271BUSD
```

Comment: Don't vandalize your post, please.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install pandas.

`pip install pandas`

2. Create an array of texts and then create a dataframe from that.

```
tickers = []
names = []
amounts = []
for i, row in enumerate(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".tv-data-table__tbody tr")):
    rest = i % 3
    if (rest == 0):
        tickers.append(row)
    if (rest == 1):
        names.append(row)
    if (rest == 2):
        amounts.append(row)




import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(tickers=tickers, names=names, amounts=amounts))
```

Comment: I have updated the answer. In order to work the list should be divisible by 3.  In other words, your list of elements should have a length that could be 0, 3 , 6, 9, 12, etc. If your list contains 2 elements for example, then the code will fail.

Comment: What happens if the table cell doesn't have a value?  I think its better to read the column name using Selenium and associate data to that column.  Can you check if you have a  CSS selector for the table header?